Decomposition of primitive central idempotents in group algebras
Let $W$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representation of a finite group $G$ with character $\chi_W$. A primitive central idempotents of the group algebra $CG$ is: $$e=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi_W(g^{-1})g.$$
Serre in his representation theory book showed if $W$ is given in matrix form $(r_{i j}(g))$ with respect to an orthogonal basis, then
$$e_{ii}=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}r_{ii}(g^{-1})g$$ are idempotent elements in $\mathbb{C}G$. Additionally, they are mutually orthogonal.
I am going to prove each $e_{ii}$ is idempotent. The fact that they are mutually orthogonal can be demonstrated with a similar argument.
In Serre's book, you can find the orthogonality relation between elements of $(r_{i j}(g))$: $$\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}r_{ij}(g^{-1})r_{pq}(g)=\begin{cases}1 \ \ \text{if}\ i=q,\ j=p \\0 \ \ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
This results in $$\color{blue}{\sum_{g \in G}r_{ii}(g^{-1})r_{ii}(gh)}=\sum_{g \in G}\bigg(r_{ii}(g^{-1})\sum_kr_{ik}(g)r_{ki}(h)\bigg)=\sum_k\bigg(\sum_{g \in G}r_{ii}(g^{-1})r_{ik}(g)\bigg)r_{ki}(h)=\frac{|G|}{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)}r_{ii}(h).$$
Therefore, $$e_{ii}^2=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)^2}{|G|^2}\sum_{g \in G}r_{ii}(g^{-1})g\sum_{t \in G}r_{ii}(t^{-1})t=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)^2}{|G|^2}\sum_{t \in G}\sum_{g \in G}r_{ii}(g^{-1})r_{ii}(t^{-1})gt\\=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)^2}{|G|^2}\sum_{h \in G}\color{blue}{\sum_{g \in G}r_{ii}(g^{-1})r_{ii}(gh^{-1})}h=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)^2}{|G|^2}\sum_{h \in G}\frac{|G|}{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)}r_{ii}(h^{-1})h\\=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W)}{|G|}\sum_{h \in G}r_{ii}(h^{-1})h=e_{ii}.$$
Since $\chi_W(g)=\sum_{i}r_{ii}(g)$, we can decompose the primitive central idempotent into a sum of non-central orthogonal idempotents: $$e=\sum_{i}e_{ii}.$$
Here is my question:
Can we extend this to any group algebra $KG$ where $|G| \in K^{\times}$?
I mean, let $V$ be irreducible $K$-representations of a finite group $G$ with character $\chi_V$. A primitive central idempotents of the group algebra $KG$ is: $$e=\frac{\dim_{K}(V)}{\dim_K(\text{End}_G(V))|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi_V(g^{-1})g.$$
Now, how can we decompose this element into a sum of orthogonal idempotents? (I am interested in the case where $K=\mathbb{R}$)
Is there any orthogonality relation between entries of the matrix form of $V$ with respect to an orthogonal basis?
